# Can you read/write a Chronicle Queue from C#?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

Is there any reasonable way to read or write to a Chronicle Queue from a C# application?  It runs on Mono on Linux if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would suggest wrapping the C/C++ version which is a licensed product.

Adding a wrapper of our own is on our roadmap.

You can contact sales@chronicle.software for more details.